# How to change Pandas.DataFrame.resample default holiday calendar?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading Wes McKinney's Python for Data Analysis book. On the topic of using `DataFrame.resample()` or `Series.resample()`, if I want to resample for Business days, I would use:

`df.resample('B')`

However, I noticed that the notation of `'B'` depends on your computer's region... I'm failing to run the examples on page 344 because my calendar isn't US...

How can I explicitly choose to resample based on a particular country's holiday? Say, US holidays, or European holidays? Struggling to find some documentation on this... The doc for `resample()` I found here {http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html} is rather short and doesn't really go into the details of the first parameter `rule`...

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> [Custom Business Days (Experimental)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days-experimental)
>
> The CDay or CustomBusinessDay class provides a parametric BusinessDay
>   class which can be used to create customized business day calendars
>   which account for local holidays and local weekend conventions.

Comment: Yea I saw that one, used it to create an US business day calendar that worked, code below:  

`from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar  
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay  
cbd = CustomBusinessDay(calenar=USFederalHolidayCalendar)`  

But there isn't any readily available calendar objects to use for other countries right? Question then is if pandas figured out I'm based in the UK so it used the UK holiday calendar, how can I make it to think I'm based somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Using the example from p. 344,  there are still U.S. holidays that are returned.  'B' is simply Mon-Fri, not a business day calendar.  Here is an example of a trading calendar based on the London Stock Exchange: https://github.com/quantopian/tradingcalendar/blob/master/zipline/utils/tradingcalendar_lse.py

Comment: Ok, maybe I got this wrong. I assumed that 'B' - meant for business days excluding public holidays. You are saying that 'B' is just the traditional weekday measure? I can explore. A bit confusing to call it business day when it does not include public holidays, should just be called weekdays instead, no?

Comment: Yes, the naming is not very clear.  Have a look at this description http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

Comment: and the offset aliases here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#offset-aliases